# Qual a diferença entre a tag <del> e <s>?

Tags: html, html-select

Vi sobre as tags `<del>` e `<s>`, dizem que uma é para ser usada em textos/frases não relevantes e outra para “deletar” parte do texto, porém ao utilizar ambas as tags o efeito é o mesmo (uma linha riscando a frase) . Qual a diferença? Muda algo eu utilizar uma ou outra?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visualmente falando o resultado é o mesmo, mas a intenção é diferente, as tags html servem para marcação, como o próprio nome sugere, ou seja, ela delimita o conteúdo, o html serve para separar as partes.

```
<del>
```

Um texto que uma parte foi deletada, e uma nova parte foi inserida.

```
<s>
```

Marca um texto que não esta correto

[Fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/)

Apesar do resultado visual ser o mesmo, a intenção é diferente, um front-end pode tratar as duas tags com uma formatação diferente, se você formatou o seu texto com o real sentido das tags o estilo do front-end vai ser aplicado corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

**A tag** `<del>` é usada para identificar o texto que foi excluído de um documento, mas retido para mostrar o histórico de modificações feitas no documento. Emparelhe um elemento `<del>` com um elemento `<ins>` para identificar o texto inserido que substituiu o texto excluído.

> Exemplo

```html
A enciclopédia mais importante do mundo é <del>Enciclopédia Britânica</del> <ins>Wikipedia</ins>.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**A tag** `<s>` é usada para identificar textos que não são mais precisos ou relevantes. É semelhante, mas semanticamente distinto, da tag `<del>` que é usada para identificar edições de documentos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -4):

O `<s>` é uma ferramenta feita para que a pessoa que olhar o código tenha a ciência de que aquela informação deve ser alterada ou corrigida. Entenda o `<s>` como uma espécie de alerta.

o `<del>`, por sua vez, faz com que o texto não seja renderizado!

Comment: Como assim não renderizado?

Comment: De onde vc tirou que o `del` não renderiza o texto? Por padrão, tanto o `del` quanto o `s` [mostram o texto do mesmo jeito](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#non-replaced-elements-phrasing-content) ("riscado"), veja [aqui](https://repl.it/@HugoKotsubo/testedels?language=html) e [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/x75y8jtw/)